# Is there a way to have a abstract method with implementations that accept different inputs

Tags: java

I am trying to do something like the following where I have an abstract method, and its implementers can accept different input objects.

```
public abstract void dostuff(Object o1, Object o2);

class 1
@Override
public void dostuff(Integer o1, Double o2){
  logic
}

class 2
@Override
public void dostuff(Double o1, Iteger o2){
  logic
}
```

real goal is to have an abstract method that can enforce some things, and not have to cast the objects once they are within the object, have that casting done automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define type variables in the abstract class:

```
abstract class AbstractClass<A, B> {
  public abstract void dostuff(A o1, B o2);
}
```

then specify the type parameters in the implementing classes:

```
class Class1 extends AbstractClass<Integer, Double> {
  @Override public void dostuff(Integer o1, Double o2) { /* ... */ }
}

class Class2 extends AbstractClass<Double, Iteger> {
  @Override public void dostuff(Double o1, Iteger o2) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to make the number of inputs varable per implementaiton... e.g. abstract class AbstractClass<A...> and have something like class1 dostuff(Integer a) class2 dostuff(integer a, double b)

Comment: Those are unrelated methods. You'd need to have two (N) base classes to define all the possible numbers of parameters.